# How can I interact with PyGrass after a script is launched?

Tags: grass-gis

From Grass GUI 7.4.1, I launch a .py script (File > launch a script) that builds maps.

How can I interact with the maps viewer, selecting the coordinates of some features, giving them as a new input to continue the process? The simple command x=input() is not operating.

Answer (score 1):

You may

- use d.what.vect for this (see Python code [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/browser/grass/trunk/scripts/d.what.vect/d.what.vect.py))
- use functions of the wxGUI interface (see Python code [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/browser/grass/trunk/gui/wxpython))
- maybe other solutions...